# When to associate an event to a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When would I associate an *event* to a *method*? For example, on a `TextBox` control, I could use the `OnTextChanged` event. If I use this event, I have to associate this event to a server side method. I would write the following line when I use the control.

```
OnTextChange = "TextBoxText_Changed"
```

But for events like `Page_Load()` I don't need to associate it with a method right? I mean I would not write something like this

```
OnPage_Load = "Page_Load"
```

Why is there difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different kinds of events. The OnTextChange one is an optional event because is not the natural behaviour of a TextBox to raise an event when its texts changes.

However, OnPage_Load event is something that always happens in the life cycle of any asp.net web page. Hence you do not have to specify this kind of events implicitly.

Take a look at the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't have asked for a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `Page_Load()` method you create is not `overriding` a `virtual` method defined in base class `Page`.

`ASP.NET` has **`AutoEventWireup`** system, which allows creating methods like Page_Load and wires up the event from base page to the method you defined in your class, in runtime. Same as you declaring `this.Load += this.Page_Load;` explicitly.

`Control` events such as `OnTextChange` of a `TextBox` (which is a Control) are not implicitly wired up.